# Windows API: Unicode variable metamorphasis

Tags: c++, string, winapi, unicode, wstring

I created a function that reads from a file, and fills a data structure based on that file. The function works well alone, so I decided to build an GUI around its function. I have a function that calls the Windows GUI and returns a `LPOPENFILENAME` structure, to which I copy the `LPOPENFILENAME.lpstrFile` over to a `LPCWSTR`.

Next, I initialize a `wstring` to hold the `LPCWSTR` value. Here's where things get a bit strange.

```
LPCWSTR File = FileOpenOBJ(hWnd, hInst).lpstrFile;
MessageBox(hWnd, File, L"Warning 1: File/lpstrFile assignment ", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
wstring Fileformatting(File);
```

Which does a runtime display of something like this:[image]

Which is fine, since `LPCWSTR File` now holds the value from the `LPOPENFILENAME` structure, but when a `wstring` is initialized with the value of `File`, both variables seemingly go out of range or pull from a pointer location that is no longer accurate and their values appear to be something like:

[image][image]

The goal is to hold the file name in a string so that I can (PHP-like) escape the `"\"` characters to insert into my function. As such:

`C:\Users\InfinityMachine\Documents\Test.obj` -> `C:\\Users\\InfinityMachine\\Documents\\Test.obj`

In which I:

```
while (Fileformatting.find(L"\\") != wstring::npos){
    Fileformatting.replace(Fileformatting.find(L"\\"), 2, L"\\\\");
}
```

How can I get the correct value of `LPCWSTR File` into `wstring Fileformatting`?

Comment: It sounds like you have a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) but it's hard to say with the code you've provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably initialized `lpstrFile` to a variable that is local to the `FileOpenOBJ` function, and when that function returns you get undefined behavior when you try to use it. It appears to work the first time because the stack hasn't been exercised yet, but that changes when you make the call to `MessageBox`.

Moving the initialization of the `wstring` would mask the problem but wouldn't fix it, you're still relying on undefined behavior. The fix would be to have the structure contain a pointer that doesn't go out of scope.

Comment: I was afraid of this but doesn't `LPCWSTR File = FileOpenOBJ(hWnd, hInst).lpstrFile;` solve this issue, by copying the value to an external variable before the function goes out of scope?

Comment: @InfinityMachine the `OPENFILE` structure returned by the function is still in scope, but that structure contains a pointer which you're supposed to set yourself. You haven't shown the body of the function where it would be set, but I'll bet I'm right that it's a local buffer. That buffer *would* go out of scope as soon as the function returns, and you're just lucky that `MessageBox` worked.

Comment: I'm going to implement your theory real quick.

Comment: I see now, thanks. I figured since the value was copied the first time, it "made it safely" and I was free to use the new variable as local. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have said about dangling pointers and such, for this kind of situation, you are better off simply having `FileOpenOBJ()` return a `wstring` instead of a copy of the original `OPENFILENAME` struct:

```
wstring FileOpenOBJ(HWND hWnd, HINSTANCE hInst)
{
    WCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH+1] = {0};

    OPENFILENAME ofn = {0};
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    ofn.hInstance = hInst;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ...

    GetOpenFileName(&ofn);
    return szFileName;
}
```

```
wstring File = FileOpenOBJ(hWnd, hInst);
MessageBoxW(hWnd, File.c_str(), L"Warning 1: File/lpstrFile assignment ", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
```

If you need to return other values from the `OPENFILENAME`, you should define your own struct to hold what you need, for example:

```
struct FileInfo
{
    wstring FullPath;
    wstring FileName;
    wstring Ext;
    int FilterIndex;
    ...
};
```

```
FileInfo FileOpenOBJ(HWND hWnd, HINSTANCE hInst)
{
    WCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH+1] = {0};

    OPENFILENAME ofn = {0};
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    ofn.hInstance = hInst;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ...

    GetOpenFileName(&ofn);

    FileInfo fi;
    fi.FullPath = szFileName;
    fi.FileName = &szFileName[ofn.nFileOffset];
    if (ofn.nFileExtension != 0)
        fi.Ext = &szFileName[ofn.nFileExtension];
    fi.FilterIndex = ofn.nFilterIndex;
    ...

    return fi;
}
```

```
FileInfo fi = FileOpenOBJ(hWnd, hInst);
MessageBoxW(hWnd, fi.FullPath.c_str(), L"Warning 1: File/lpstrFile assignment ", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
```

Don't expose direct access to the `OPENFILENAME` struct.  It should be left as a private implementation detail of `FileOpenOBJ()`'s internal logic.

Comment: This was thorough. I ended up doing: `if (GetOpenFileNameW(&OpenFilenameDesc)){ wstring File(OpenFilenameDesc.lpstrFile); return File; }`

Comment: I can't accept two answers, but both answers accurately resolved the scoping issue.

Comment: Since the return value is a `wstring`, you can omit the temp `wstring File` variable and return the `lpstrFile` directly, the compiler will perform an implicit `wstring` assignment for you (especially useful if the compiler implements [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)): `if (GetOpenFileNameW(&OpenFilenameDesc)){ return OpenFilenameDesc.lpstrFile; }`